# Trying to hide a table on if attribute value of another element changes

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

EDIT: jQuery change function does not work on divs.

I am trying to hide a table row with class `.card-text-field`,

when `.wooco_component_product[data-name='Kaartje'] input.dd-selected-value` has a value of "-1",

Concerns this live website: https://alpin.nl/product/rond-boeket/

I tried the below code:

```
$('.wooco_component_product[data-name="Kaartje"] .dd-selected-value').change(function(e){
    let value = $(this).val();
  if (value == "-1") {
     $('.card-text-field').addClass("hidden-card-text-field");
  }
  else {
    $('.card-text-field').removeClass("hidden-card-text-field");
  }
});
```

I can't seem to make it work :( any suggestions?

Comment: In "kaartje" I assume you ment the "Card" option - but that has data-name "Card" no kaartje - besides you can use  $(this).data('id') == 0 you don't need to mention the entire attribute

Comment: This depends on whether you are viewing the page in the English or Dutch language version. For now I am testing on the Dutch version. Indeed, the solution will also be implemented for the English language version.

Comment: 1) why use a different name (element and code should be language agnostic) 2) why use the data-attribute as selector (and not just an ID) it's easier ?

Comment: Ideally, yes, but we are dealing with a standard WC solution, so I am going to steer away from making adjustments to the theme codes, etc. Plus, thanks for your comments, but not in scope of the question ;-)

Comment: Take a look at this small sample https://jsfiddle.net/svz4dha2/

Comment: Many thanks again. This, and slightly similar scenario's, I've managed to make work. Note, however, that I am dealing with the specific circumstances described above, i.e. a change of an element attribute that should trigger the toggle. If only it were a select-field: that would be much easier indeed :-)